# How to create a matrix and loop over cells?

Tags: r

I would like to create a matrix, and then based on an equation calculate each cell of the matrix using the given values in the particular column and row names.

This is the empty matrix that I created.

```
T <- seq(from=-4, to=0, by=0.05)
S <- seq(from=15, to=30, by=0.5)
matrix2 <- matrix(nrow = 81, ncol = 31)
dimnames(matrix2) = list(T, S)
```

Now I would like to calculate each cell for the corresponding row and column (T and S) using this equation

```
1-exp(-(T^(1/0.9)+S^(1/0.9))^0.9)
```

Do I need a loop here or something else?

Comment: Please check your formula as I get the `NaN` in some of the elements. `1-exp(-(T[1]^(1/0.9)+S[1]^(1/0.9))^0.9)#
[1] NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `outer`

```
matrix2[] <- outer(T, S, FUN = f1)
```

where

```
f1 <- function(x, y) 1-exp(-(x^(1/0.9)+y^(1/0.9))^0.9)
```